# Unable to call microservice using HttpClient

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, windows-services, openapi, dotnet-httpclient

I am using OpenApi (NSwag) to create the client that uses `HttpClient` to call a micro service. Now when I run my application from Visual Studio, it works fine and I can call my service using `HttpClient`, but I am hosting my project as a Windows service, and when the Windows service tries to call the micro service, it throws the following error:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I am running my micro service locally and using localhost url

Comment: Your service has an invalid SSL certificate it seems.

Comment: how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Common reason of "invalid certificate" is that the domain of certificate is not same as the domain you are calling. But no matter what the reason is, an easy way to solve is bypass the certificate validation when create httpclient.

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>{return true;};
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient(httpClientHandler));
```

Or add some validation if you want

```
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => {
    if (cert.GetCertHashString() == "A7E2BA992F4F2BE220559B8A5371F05A00A6E750") //FingerPrint of the certificate
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```